# jqxgrid beforeLoadComplete callback method

Tags: javascript, jquery

As per the documentation on jqxgrid callback method beforeLoadComplete

https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxdataadapter/jquery-data-adapter.htm

The function gets passed two arguments: The loaded records. The second argument is the original data.

However, while implementing the same i.e. I have a web service call
/myService

& I get the following response

```
{"lastRefresh":"01/12/2016","items":[{"country":"US","location":"US","deletedBy":""},
{"country":"US","location":"US","deletedBy":""}],"numRows"
:"2","noDataMessage":null,"errorMessage":null,"total":"100"}
```

Now in my beforeLoadComplete callback method;

```
beforeLoadComplete : function(records) {
// Here records is set to the "items" array and not the complete response
}
```

records is set to the "items" array and not the complete response.
My question is how do I access the complete JSON response inside the beforeLoadComplete callback.

Comment: Did you try to define `beforeLoadComplete : function(records, data)` ? If it doesn't work, you may try with `downloadComplete` to workaround...